How do I mask the "Add or Remove button" option from CMFCToolBar
i want to use the docking feature of the CMFCToolBar, at the same time i want to hide the menu items automatically generated by the framework.
Remove or mask the drop-down triangle, do not want the "add or remove button" option.

Just comment out this line of code:
m_wndToolBar.EnableCustomizeButton(TRUE, ID_VIEW_CUSTOMIZE, strCustomize); 

Do not enable the custom button.
